# jQuery infinite two-way animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need a little help with my code. I have defined a an infinite animatine with callback function. Infinite animation works excellent for me, BUT:

- some text should moves to left and then back to initial position (smoothly)

Do I need a second animation or? I think that the problem will be in the last argument ($(this).css(...)). This make a quick move to the... not nice at all.

```
$(function () {
    var moveBasic = function () {
        $('ul#softfacts div.basic').delay(1000).animate({
            'margin-left': '+=5px'
        }, 1000, 'linear', function () {
            $(this).css({
                'margin-left': '+=5px'
            });
            moveBasic();
        });
    }
    moveBasic();
});
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `animate()` again:

```
$(this).animate({
    marginLeft: '-=5px'
}).promise().done(function () {
    moveBasic()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this refers to global object. try using $('ul#softfacts div.basic') instead of this.